# Should I explicitly tell the compiler to move the string in this case?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, move-semantics

```
void SomeClass::setName(std::string name)
{
    name_ = std::move(name);
}
```

Is this explicit `std::move()` redundant for the compiler?

Comment: If you want move semantics, use `std::move`.

Comment: Implicit `move` from named variable might only happen for return statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this explicit std::move() redundant for the compiler?

No. Without `std::move()` the operand would be an lvalue and thus you would be using the copy assignment operator.

Comment: I vaguely recall 'last use before scope ends is implicit move' being suggested, but I don't know what, if anything, came of it.

Comment: I'd be curious to hear the rationale against 'last use before scope ends is implicit move'. Probably some edge case I'm not seeing that is obvious to a compiler programmer.